# How can I find results from an ObjectId field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have a schema like this:

```
var Word = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    language: { type: ObjectId, ref: "Language", required: true }
});
```

and I try to query it like this

```
var language = "5078547df6b753bc06000003";
word.find({ language: language }, function (err, words) {
  console.log(words);
});
```

I get an empty result set (`[]`). I know there exists a word with this language, because if I remove the `{language: language}` I get this object:

```
[{
  "_id": "5079fd7b6df57b1b64cbf25d",
  "name": "dog",
  "language": "5078547df6b753bc06000003",
}]
```

I've tried using

```
var language = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5078547df6b753bc06000003");
word.find({ language: language }, //etc.
```

but it still returns an empty result set.

Why can't mongoose find the word with this language id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the `language` field as an ObjectId in the schema, but in the MongoDB document it's actually a string.  So in your `find` call, Mongoose is going to cast the `language` variable to an ObjectId and then the query will return any documents where `language` is an ObjectId with that value (and won't find any because it's not an ObjectId in the database).

You either need to update the document so that `language` contains an ObjectId instead of a string or change your schema so that `language` is defined as `type: String`.  If you want to treat `language` as  a reference as you're doing in the schema then you'll need to do the former.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I inserted a string value into the field, assuming it would automatically be converted into an ObjectId

Comment: @PeterOlson It will convert the string to an ObjectId if you create the doc via a mongoose `create` call (or `new` and `save`), but not if you use some other way.